# Magento SUPEE-6788 Breaks email body in all email templates

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-6788

When I enable this security patch, all emails sent have no body. When I look at the email header I see this inside all of them `dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)`

I have an exception log:

http://pastebin.com/JPCY6qfZ

I'm not much of a Magento/PHP guy to begin with, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I want to re-apply the security patch, but I need email functionality otherwise our store is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get ours back to working by flushing the magento cache.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even try that. Thanks! Seems to have done the trick!